# Is the Fourier transform of a compactly supported distribution a symbol?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, pseudo-differential-operators

I am learning some pseudo-differential operator and wondering is the Fourier transform of a compactly supported distribution a symbol, which gives a way to interpret the Fourier Inversion for those distributions.

By symbol I mean $|\partial^\alpha_x\partial^\beta_\xi a(x,\xi)|\leq C_{\alpha,\beta}(1+|\xi|)^{m-|\beta|}$ for some $m$ (in this case, our $a$ does not depend on $x$).

Comment: $\|\widehat{f}\|_\infty \le \|f\|_{L^1} \le \pi \|(1+x^2)f\|_{\infty} $ thus the Fourier transform is continuous from the Schwartz space to itself (which means $\sum_{b \le m, a \le m} \|x^b \partial_a \widehat{f}\|_\infty \le C_{m} \sum_{b \le N_m, a \le N_m} \|x^b \partial_a f\|_\infty$)

Comment: But I mean compactly supported distribution...

Comment: Can you use what I wrote to state precisely what you want ?

Comment: The Fourier transform of a compactly supported distribution is $C^\infty$ function (which can be extended to a analytic entire function) and is bounded by a polynomial. I just want to know if it also belongs to the symbol class.

Comment: It's at the end of the question.

Comment: Are you kidding ? You just said if $f$ is a compactly supported distribution then $\forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}, |\hat{f}(\xi)|= |\langle  f,e^{-2i \pi \xi x} \rangle| \le C (1+|\xi|^m)$ (this is a direct consequence of distributions and compactly supported). What do you want to know then ?

Comment: Perhaps see the Wiki page on "Paley-Wiener theorem".